# What does it take to build a 'Build your own car' application in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am newbie flash developer who is bidding for a project that aims to clone [this](http://www.hummer.com/hummerjsp/home.jsp). So, how tough is designing a tool that let's you customize your car? What areas of flash should I bet good at? and really good at? If you notice, there is lot of browsing that is happening in the background in the site I shared even when you build you own hummer.

Can someone tell me where to get started for this? Or, should I just give it up coz its way difficult for a newbie to accomplish? Also, what kind of money is involved in this kind of projects?

Comment: UPDATE: I withdrew from the bidding. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really difficult and time consuming. Usually it takes a team of photographers, graphic designers, and developers.

If you are not qualified to do all 3 then make sure you have access to them before bidding.

Look at image manipulation with Flex/Flash -

SEE: http://www.insideria.com/2008/03/image-manipulation-in-flex.html

You need to be an expert at this.

Know Flash Effects.

SEE: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/graphic_effects.html

Also it is important to Know ActionScript 3 and AMF. Take a look at the Adobe ActionScript 3 component and language reference.

Answer (score 5):

I would be really, really careful before bidding for something like this. You definitely should have some experience with big industrial clients (I am assuming from the project that it's not a small business down the road), and with the workflow of a complicated flash project.

This is going to be extremely demanding on both the design/UI and the data processing end, plus there may be requirements on the client side to a car configurator that are completely invisible from the outside.

To make a solid estimate, you'll need lots of project experience. If you make a too low estimate, you'll be grinding your teeth half way in because you realize is 3-4 times more work than you expected, and you can't back down any more.

I would say, hands off. Start with something smaller, or maybe partner up with somebody with experience in the field.

Comment: @Pekka I wish I could choose both yours and Todd's answers. Both of them provided the necessary insight. I am giving it to Todd for sharing some links! Thank you for your response.